# Ruby Net::SSH Change directories using variable interpolation

Tags: ruby, ssh, exec

I am fairly new to Ruby, so please forgive me if I am missing something obvious.

The problem is that Ruby doesn't seem to be doing variable interpolation in the Net::SSH.exec! method.

```
VCL_DIR = "/usr/local/etc/varnish/"
host = '0.0.0.0'
Net::SSH.start(host, 'root') do |ssh|
  puts "Changing directories to #{VCL_DIR}"
  ssh.exec!("cd #{VCL_DIR}")
  res = ssh.exec!("pwd")
  puts "Server reports current directory as #{res}"
end
```

Output:

```
Changing directories to /usr/local/etc/varnish/
Server reports current directory as /root
```

Any help is appreciated.  Using Ruby 1.9.3p194

Comment: String interpolation happens before (and independent of) any method invocation where the string may be passed as a parameter. You can be sure that your code above is the same as `ssh.exec!("cd /usr/local/etc/varnish")`; your problem lies elsewhere from what you are suspecting and describing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Net::SSH uses a different shell for each exec call.  The solution is to use stateful shell.  There is a gem to do this, but it is outdated.  Net::SSH::Shell via https://github.com/mitchellh/net-ssh-shell

I chose to use Rye to handle this task. http://code.google.com/p/rye/

Comment: Do you still use Rye with newer versions of Ruby?

Comment: I quit using Ruby,

Answer (score 0):

`Net::SSH.start( "10.2.10.1", "botp:)", :password=>"secret=)") do
|session|
  puts session.exec! "ls -la; cd /etc; ls -la"
end`

Reference: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/160890

> Please note: you have to "cd" per each `.exec!` command ran.
>   Something like below, will show you that using cd in one exec! command does not change the location for the next exec command.

`Net::SSH.start( "10.2.10.1", "botp:)", :password=>"secret=)") do
|session|
  puts session.exec!("ls -la; cd /etc; ls -la")
  puts session.exec!("ls -la")
end`