# Ruby use local defined variable to a remote server connection

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-ssh

Here is what i want to do:

```
VAR_NAME="lala123"

Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER ) do |ssh|
  create_file = ssh.exec!('sudo mkdir /path/to/; \
                           sudo touch /path/to/file; \
                           sudo echo #{VAR_NAME} > /path/to/file')
end
```

The problem is similar with this one

[Ruby Net::SSH Change directories using variable interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606290/ruby-netssh-change-directories-using-variable-interpolation)

but i didn't find a way to resolve it with net/ssh neither with Rye.
Any hint will be extremly appreciated :).

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **'** instead of **"**

The first symbol does not interpolates. While the second one (") does.